# How can I advance?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice

Right now I am 13. I have studied at the normal pace at my school, however, since this academic year I have felt that the pace the classes move at are too slow and I wish to advance faster. I would like to know how I can advance in maths and whether I should be advancing or staying at the set pace of my class?

Comment: I would think you can start by filling out your schedule with an english reading and writing class...

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It's hard to answer this...I mean, it's hard to give an answer which would work for all students.  If you can, I think you'd do better to ask one of your teachers to recommend some outside reading or work. It's really a lot better to do this with someone than to try it entirely on your own.

Comment: Is there a sympathetic teacher at your school you can talk with about this?

Comment: There is no reason to stay at a set pace. Today you can learn from many places. Here. Wikipedia, Youtube... There is lots of course material freely available up until at least first few years of university.

Comment: Very often math classes at that level are taken by many students who are there only because it is required of them or only because they want to get good grades. The rate at which material is covered needs to be what those sorts of students can handle. Generally that will be too slow for someone who actually wants to learn the subject. Thus it is appropriate for such a student to seek ways to learn faster.

Comment: The best place to learn math is from math.stackexchange.com. Fact. Just stay updated on this site, you will get plenty of questions to answer, and plenty of food for thought. I have experienced the same lull in my courses as you have, and stackexchange has rounded me very well as a student of mathematics. I am full of praise for this site. Even if you are $13$, you will get excellent questions even at that level (as I did challenge myself at that age).

Comment: Have you begun to study algebra yet? If not, you might want to ask your teacher if there is an older copy of the textbook used for beginning algebra that you could borrow. These might be at the back of your (or another) classroom (or in a classroom closet, or somewhere in a book storage room). In fact, you might just ask for an older copy of the math book used for the grade level after the grade level you are in. Besides public and school library books, this is how I learned essentially all of high school math on my own when I was in the 8th and 9th grades (ages 13 to 15).

Comment: Focus on understanding and use symbolab and wolfram alpha. Use the computer to solve any problem he can solve. Your job is to understand the concepts and apply the them.

Answer (score 5):

In today's world there's so much you can find online or at the library (local/community college/research institute). Continue to take math classes at school as there's value in group learning and having a teacher to answer questions, but by all means continue to push yourself and learn more. If you have an approachable math teacher, you might want to talk with them to gain further insights on what you should do next.

**Online Sources**

I would suggest to look to online sources such as [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/). There they provide videos where you can touch up on things you have learned (perhaps algebra and arithmetic) and continue to learn more such as pre-calculus and on. The videos go up thru calculus, differential equations and linear algebra, which can be the equivalent of the first two years of undergrad.

*This site* can be a great learning tool. Ask questions and see if there's any you can answer. You'll learn a lot by just browsing around here.

Read math blogs or watch math videos on YouTube. [*Note:* These are generally not rigorous learning sources for independent study, but imo they help peak curiosity and are just cool] Some of my favorites are [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile/featured), [Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg), and [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) who all provide very interesting and fun examples and inquiries into math.

**Books**

Under the [[reference-request]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag here on this site you can find several books and articles in a large variety of subjects that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Local libraries don't usually have much on the undergraduate/advanced high-school level. (I live in an area with a number of research institutes and the local libraries weren't helpful.) I'd suggest instead the science/engineering library at a local college or university.

Comment: Also, people might find Numberphile entertaining, but as far as independent learning I doubt that's a valuable source....

Comment: Oh, perhaps my local library is special. They have a couple textbooks in undergraduate maths.

Comment: @Chris I agree. That's why I listed several other things. But I also think adding a little fun or entertainment to peak curiosity and instigate further study is important. I'll add a little disclaimer.

Comment: @Chris: "*undergraduate/advanced high-school level*" At 13 the OP is probably well below this level, likely not even in high school, which makes the situation you describe worse. However, 4-year college libraries, and especially community college libraries (if in the U.S.) are much better hunting grounds. However, better still is the local public library, unless this is a rural area in which the public library has few "nonfiction books" (a situation I've encountered in some places I've lived), and thus essentially no math books.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I appreciate your concerns, and I may have overestimated the background of OP. My feeling is that the OP should pick up the rudiments of trigonometry and algebra, either in courses or by self-learning, and then try a book like the one I recommended.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely want to advance if you can. The syllabus used in class is supposed to accommodate your average student, so if you want to be good or exceptional at maths you will have to put in work yourself.

The first thing I recommend to do is to talk to your teacher and make sure you and him are on the same page. That means he might try to stretch you more and not give you just what the rest of the class receives.

Secondly, do not cover material which you will cover later on in school. A prime example of this is calculus. Calculus will make up a big chunk of your maths education at school when you are 16/17/18 years old. Don't spoil the fun of learning about it then by covering now, otherwise classes will seem even more easy and as a result boring.

Stemming from the last point, at your age Olympiads are the natural path to go for. Once you become relatively good at them, they are great fun, especially if you become seriously good at them and get to travel to exotic places for things like the IMO. I personally enjoyed working through the 'Art of Problem Solving' series and from there working through Olympiads from around the world. Once you acquire a basic arsenal of mathematical weapons you can enquire into other books which might specialise into Number Theory, Geometry etc.

I hope this answers your question. If you have any follow up queries just comment down below.

Comment: I agree about not learning stuff that comes later. (+1)  Better to be adventerous I think.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree. Learning calculus has been awesome for me, and so much the better if I can test out of it or review it further. Besides, calculus can be fun in lower level math - using calculus, for example, to prove that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471135712) book *incredibly* useful. Actual textbooks on more advanced mathematics, at your age, can feel incredibly dense and abstract from the kind of problems you're interested in. I prefer to learn by solving problems, and this book neatly combines problem solving with an introduction to formal mathematical reasoning (like proofs by induction, and by contradiction). There's also a newer version which includes more geometry!

If you want more recommendations, feel free to ask, but my fundamental advice is: go at your own pace, and don't feel compelled to try to hit advanced material at age 13. If you like solving problems, solve problems - don't feel compelled to learn calculus "because you should be doing that." You'll get there on your own one way or another - but if you go at your own pace, you'll enjoy it more.